# IOS Objective-C Make appear a application in all "open in"

Tags: ios, objective-c

I develop an application named NAS, and I want to launch video from external applications into my app NAS.

Has you can see in the screenshot, I can "Open in" mail but not in the Synology app "DS File"...

[image]

For the first case I add this code into info.plist :

```
<key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeIconFiles</key>
        <array>
            <string>Document-molecules-320.png</string>
            <string>Document-molecules-64.png</string>
        </array>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string>Video File</string>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Viewer</string>
        <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
        <string>Owner</string>
        <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
        <array>
        <string>public.mpeg-4</string>
        <string>public.avi</string>
        <string>public.mpeg</string>
        <string>com.apple.quicktime-movie</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
```

How can I add the link to my app NAS in the second case ?

NB : in the two case, I open an .avi file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second case is someone else's custom app.

They appear to have written the action sheet themselves only using apps that they have chosen.

No amount of code on your part will change that.

The best way to appear in that list is to contact Synology and ask them to add you in and supply details of how to open your app with the relevant file.